# How can I prevent Sphinx from listing "object" as a base class?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-sphinx

I have this class:

```
class Class:
    pass
```

The documentation generated by sphinx (in case it matters, I used the `autodoc` extension) looks like this:

> *class* package.**Class**
>
> Bases: **object**

The inheritance from `object` isn't useful information for the reader, and therefore I don't want it in my documentation. The output I'd like to see is this:

> *class* package.**Class**

---

Is there a way to exclude `object` from the list of base classes?

Comment: I guess you use `automodule` directive to document every module member?

Comment: @hoefling Yes. My `module.rst` contains the usual `.. automodule:: module :members: :undoc-members: :show-inheritance:` as generated by `sphinx-apidoc`.

Comment: maybe [autodoc-process-bases](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#event-autodoc-process-bases) could be relevant?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is actually deeply embedded in [the `autodoc` source code](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/ext/autodoc/__init__.py#L1195), with no way to turn it off:

```
bases = [b.__module__ in ('__builtin__', 'builtins') and
         u':class:`%s`' % b.__name__ or
         u':class:`%s.%s`' % (b.__module__, b.__name__)
         for b in self.object.__bases__]
self.add_line(u'   ' + _(u'Bases: %s') % ', '.join(bases), sourcename)
```

`object` isn't given any special treatment; there's no builtin way to exclude it from the list.

---

The best (automatic) solution I could find was to monkeypatch autodoc.

Adding this to `conf.py` enables the desired behavior:

```
# ClassDocumenter.add_directive_header uses ClassDocumenter.add_line to
#   write the class documentation.
# We'll monkeypatch the add_line method and intercept lines that begin
#   with "Bases:".
# In order to minimize the risk of accidentally intercepting a wrong line,
#   we'll apply this patch inside of the add_directive_header method.

from sphinx.ext.autodoc import ClassDocumenter, _

add_line = ClassDocumenter.add_line
line_to_delete = _(u'Bases: %s') % u':class:`object`'

def add_line_no_object_base(self, text, *args, **kwargs):
    if text.strip() == line_to_delete:
        return

    add_line(self, text, *args, **kwargs)

add_directive_header = ClassDocumenter.add_directive_header

def add_directive_header_no_object_base(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.add_line = add_line_no_object_base.__get__(self)

    result = add_directive_header(self, *args, **kwargs)

    del self.add_line

    return result

ClassDocumenter.add_directive_header = add_directive_header_no_object_base
```

Comment: For me, `add_directive_header_no_object_base` never gets called (I added a print statement there and did not get anything on the output).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Sphinx is doing some magic with the console (for pretty output), so output from your print is just overwritten. Try to add more `\n`s.

Answer (score 3):

As for Jun 2022 and Sphinx v5.0.1, Aran-Fey's answer is a bit outdated; the solution that worked in my case was replace this line:

```
line_to_delete = _('Bases: %s') % ':class:`object`'
```

with this:

```
line_to_delete = _('Bases: %s') % ':py:class:`object`'
```

Comment: For me, `add_directive_header_no_object_base` never gets called (I added a print statement there and did not get anything on the output).

Comment: I think it's time to remove `u`. I mean strings are Unicode by default now. And, by the way, I prefer to clarify `from sphinx.ext.autodoc import _ as localize`, because I don't think I'll remember that `_` is localization function.

Comment: Well, you don't have to _remember_ that, AFAIK its a de facto standard, because I personally encountered this naming convention at least in Python, PHP, and also Android Java (not 100% sure about last one, though), all in different companies.

Removed `u`s

Comment: BTW, the main purpose of  `_`  in this context is to make code with a lot of localized strings compact and readable, and one way to achieve this is to use an alias, shorter the better. I wouldn't say `localize()`  is short.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: This may not be the best or most elegant solution, because the more plain classes you have (that subclass `object` only), the more work you will have to do as you have to preprocess each class manually.

---

If you are using `autoclass` directive to document the class, simply don't use the `:show-inheritance:` option. If you are using `automodule` to generate documentation for all module members, turning `:show-inheritance:` off will not help as no base classes will be documented for each class in module. Thus, I would go with the following:

**Step 1**: Document the class outside of the module without `:show-inheritance:` like this:

```
my\.mod module
--------------

.. automodule:: my.mod
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:

.. autoclass:: Class
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
```

**Step 2**: Filter class `Class` out of module's `automodule` documentation in your `conf.py` via [`autodoc-skip-member` hook](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html#event-autodoc-skip-member):

```
def skip_some_classes(app, what, name, obj, skip, options):
    return skip or name in ('Class',)  # define some better condition here

def setup(app):
    app.connect('autodoc-skip-member', skip_some_classes)
```

This way, all module members except `Class` will be processed with `:show-inheritance:` option, while `Class` is treated separately.

Comment: Thanks, this works. It requires a bit more manual work than I'd like though. I can already picture myself refactoring my class's inheritance tree and forgetting to update the rst files. A completely automatic solution is what I'm really after.

Comment: By the way, you can define `skip_some_classes` as `return skip or (isinstance(obj, type) and obj.__base__ is object)`.

Comment: yes, I don't like the solution either because of that. the maintenance costs may be enormous if the project is still being developed.

Comment: Problem is, I don't see a simple way of automating that by using autodoc hooks only. You can of course monkeypatch the `sphinx.apidoc` module and overwrite e.g. the [`create_module_file`](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/apidoc.py#L96) function, doing some kind of postprocessing with separating plain classes from being automoduled, but this is probably even more hassle and probably not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

For me, worked really simple solution.

```py
from sphinx.ext import autodoc

class MockedClassDocumenter(autodoc.ClassDocumenter):
    def add_line(self, line: str, source: str, *lineno: int) -> None:
        if line == "   Bases: :py:class:`object`":
            return
        super().add_line(line, source, *lineno)

autodoc.ClassDocumenter = MockedClassDocumenter
```

In the `conf.py`.